# How can I get letters in an expression on Python

Tags: python, expression, letters-and-numbers

I have this expression:

```
<a class="a-link-normal" href="https://www.amazon.it/Philips-GC8735-PerfectCare-Generatore-Vapore/dp/B01J5FGW66/ref=gbph_img_s-3_7347_c3de3e94?smid=A11IL2PNWYJU7H&amp;pf_rd_p=82ae57d3-a26a-4d56-b221-3155eb797347&amp;pf_rd_s=slot-3&amp;pf_rd_t=701&amp;pf_rd_i=gb_main&amp;pf_rd_m=A11IL2PNWYJU7H&amp;pf_rd_r=MDQJBKEMGBX38XMPSHXB" id="dealImage"></a>
```

And I need to get the 10 letters next to "/dp/"  (B01J5FGW66)

How can I make a function that do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regex:

```
import re
s = '<a class="a-link-normal" href="https://www.amazon.it/Philips-GC8735-PerfectCare-Generatore-Vapore/dp/B01J5FGW66/ref=gbph_img_s-3_7347_c3de3e94?smid=A11IL2PNWYJU7H&amp;pf_rd_p=82ae57d3-a26a-4d56-b221-3155eb797347&amp;pf_rd_s=slot-3&amp;pf_rd_t=701&amp;pf_rd_i=gb_main&amp;pf_rd_m=A11IL2PNWYJU7H&amp;pf_rd_r=MDQJBKEMGBX38XMPSHXB" id="dealImage"></a>'
print(re.search(r"dp\/([A-Za-z0-9]{10})\/", s)[1])
```

Output:`B01J5FGW66`

Explanation:

begin at `"dp/"`:

```
dp\/
```

capture group delimited by () matching 10 (through {10}) small letters(a-z), capital letters(A-Z) and numbers(0-9):

```
([A-Za-z0-9]{10})
```

end at `"/"`:

```
\/
```

using `re.search` we can search for that expression in your string `s`and acces the results for the 1st capture group with `[1]`.

**Note** that you might want to add extra code in case no match is found:

```
m = re.search(r"dp\/([A-Za-z0-9]{10})\/", s)
if m is not None:
    print(m[1])
else:
    # if nothing is found, search return None
    print("No match")
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I understand everything, but I have a last error:                    **return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object**                                                     I tried with str() but do not works

Comment: What is the type of the variable you are giving to `search` as second argument

Comment: the type is **<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>** how can I resolve this?

Comment: Try adding `["href"]`

Comment: What do you mean for "add"? I have a variable that contain the scrape of the page how can I do the "adding"?

Comment: if your variable was named `s`, try `re.search(r"dp\/([A-Za-z0-9]{10})\/", s["href"])`

Comment: it says `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you always just want what's between the slashes next to dp (the next route), and that the 10 characters is kind of irrelevant. A little clunky, but this works:

```
>>> x = '<a class="a-link-normal" href="https://www.amazon.it/Philips-GC8735-PerfectCare-Generatore-Vapore/dp/B01J5FGW66/ref=gbph_img_s-3_7347_c3de3e94?smid=A11IL2PNWYJU7H&amp;pf_rd_p=82ae57d3-a26a-4d56-b221-3155eb797347&amp;pf_rd_s=slot-3&amp;pf_rd_t=701&amp;pf_rd_i=gb_main&amp;pf_rd_m=A11IL2PNWYJU7H&amp;pf_rd_r=MDQJBKEMGBX38XMPSHXB" id="dealImage"></a>'
>>> splits = x.split("/")
>>> dp_index = splits.index('dp')
>>> result = splits[dp_index+1] # Get the next one over
>>> result
'B01J5FGW66'
```

to put it in a funciton, you can do it like this:

```
def get_route_next_to_dp(html_str):
    splits = html_str.split("/")
    dp_index = splits.index('dp')
    result = splits[dp_index+1] # Get the next one over
    return result
```

Usage might look like:

```
html_str = '<a class="a-link-normal" href="https://www.amazon.it/Philips-GC8735-PerfectCare-Generatore-Vapore/dp/B01J5FGW66/ref=gbph_img_s-3_7347_c3de3e94?smid=A11IL2PNWYJU7H&amp;pf_rd_p=82ae57d3-a26a-4d56-b221-3155eb797347&amp;pf_rd_s=slot-3&amp;pf_rd_t=701&amp;pf_rd_i=gb_main&amp;pf_rd_m=A11IL2PNWYJU7H&amp;pf_rd_r=MDQJBKEMGBX38XMPSHXB" id="dealImage"></a>'
route_next_to_dp = get_route_next_to_dp(html_str)
print(route_next_to_dp)
```

outputs

```
'B01J5FGW66'
```

as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: it basically uses regular expression and count the next 10 strings and check if it is found.

```
import re
my_string='<a class="a-link-normal" href="https://www.amazon.it/Philips-GC8735-PerfectCare-Generatore-Vapore/dp/B01J5FGW66/ref=gbph_img_s-3_7347_c3de3e94?smid=A11IL2PNWYJU7H&amp;pf_rd_p=82ae57d3-a26a-4d56-b221-3155eb797347&amp;pf_rd_s=slot-3&amp;pf_rd_t=701&amp;pf_rd_i=gb_main&amp;pf_rd_m=A11IL2PNWYJU7H&amp;pf_rd_r=MDQJBKEMGBX38XMPSHXB" id="dealImage"></a>'
m = re.search(r"dp\/([A-Za-z0-9]{10})\/", my_string)
if m.group(1):
    print(m.group(1))
```